# What is someone called who makes and sells sandwiches?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, agent-nouns

I am translating a text from Persian to English. I need to use an equivalent for "ساندویچی" (pronounced 'Sandwichi')(In Persian, a person who makes and sells sandwiches. It also applies to the place, where this is done). 
I found *snack bar* that can be used for the place (sandwich shop), but no equivalent for the employee therein. Is there such a word in English?

Comment: I don't think there's a single-word equivalent.

Comment: I'm told it's *artist* but I am not 100% convinced.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is an English word for such a narrow profession.  Someone who makes food is generally called a "cook" or a "chef" if they're highly trained.  However, we don't have dozens and dozens of *types* of cooks (one for sandwiches, one for pizzas, one for hamburgers, etc.)

Comment: _Sandwitcheer_. Doens't really exists but sound cool.

Comment: @keshlam Define *word*.

Comment: OK: "A common, well-known, and accepted English word", if you prefer. By definition you can invent one, but "Is there such a word" usually means "is there a word or short phrase that the majority of native speakers will immediately recognize as having this meaning, and will consider natural" And as far as I know, the answer is "no", at least outside the jargon of the food-service profession. I would be pleased to be wrong, but then again I would have considered the use of "barrista" to mean coffee server jargon before Storebought's popularized it.

Comment: I don’t see that a term with no spaces in its standard orthography has anything over one that doesn’t. So a place where one buys sandwiches is a *sandwich shop*. Everybody would know that and agree.  Whether you spell it without a space makes no difference.

Comment: I love coining new terms! - paninist - sammy - hero - wicher (pronounced "witcher") - submariner - sandman - dagwood - earl (you know .. like the earl of Sandwich)

Comment: Along with @Lohoris,  I'd also consider a *sandwicher*. (It's use support appears to be primarily Germany as a restaurant, a [french verb](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/sandwicher.php), and belonging to the Sandwich Islands). However, it seems analogous to baker (versus *bakeer*), along with the idea of one who sandwiches items between slices of bread.

Comment: I used to work at subway a long time ago. We were known as 'Sandwich Artists'

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A person who makes sandwiches is a *sandwich maker*.

A person who sells sandwiches is a *sandwich vendor*.

A person who buys sandwiches is a *sandwich buyer*.

A person who loves sandwiches is a *sandwich lover*.

A person who eats sandwiches is no longer hungry.

Answer (score 25):

I'm tempted to suggest **sandwich-maker**, the only problem with this term is that some might think of the electrical device used for toasting *filled sandwiches*

[image: images of George Forman Grill, pannini presses and other appliances to toast/modify sandwiches.]

However, in context, its meaning would be unequivocal.

> - Doug worked as a sandwich-maker until the day before he was fired.
> - It is said that the sandwich-maker was occupied two hours in cutting and arranging the sandwiches for the day's consumption.
> - Who Makes The Most Delicious Sandwiches - A Professional [Sandwich-Maker](http://www.epicurious.com/articlesguides/blogs/editor/2014/07/who-makes-the-most-delicious-sandwiches-a-professional-sandwich-maker-or-300-sandwiches-stephanie-sm.html) Or 300 Sandwiches' Stephanie Smith?

EDIT/UPDATE: From today's [Daily Mail](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B2CC_ovCMAAGCOg.jpg) (Nov 10 2014), one of Britains best selling tabloid newspapers, has the following dramatic headline

### 1. Is There No One Left in Britain Who Can Make a Sandwich?

> **The UK’s biggest sandwich maker** wants to recruit hundreds of workers
>   from Eastern Europe because no Britons will do the job. Bosses from
>   Greencore Group are flying to Hungary today in search of staff for its
>   new factory.
>   ....
>   Allyson Russell, Greencore’s human resources director, said the
>   company had tried to recruit in the UK, but that it was ‘not always
>   the kind of work’ which people wanted to do

And from the website [World Bakers.com](http://www.worldbakers.com/436-sandwich-maker-teams-up-with-biscuit-firm) the same sandwich maker company is nominated in the article

### 2. Sandwich maker teams up with biscuit firm

> Northern Foods has unveiled plans to merge with the biggest **sandwich
>   maker in the UK**, creating a group with annual sales of £1.7 billion. Northern Foods, makers of Fox's biscuits, hopes to complete the tie-up with Irish chilled foods firm Greencore by the end of June.

All of which suggests that the term *sandwich maker* not only applies to the worker/s who make/s the sandwiches but also to the company or store/sandwich bar that makes *and* sells them. Something which I should have mentioned as soon as I realized that the OP was looking for one term which covered both bases.

Well as they say, *the proof is in the eating*...

Comment: There is also [Arthur Dent - The Sandwich Maker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Places_in_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Lamuella)

Comment: Perhaps you could use "sandwich preparer" to make a distinction from "sandwich maker".

Comment: I'd go for "Mom"

Answer (score 17):

The fast food chain Subway calls their employees "sandwich artists," though I think it's somewhat tongue-in-cheek since the sandwiches they sell are pretty unexceptional.

I have never heard the term "sandwich bar." At least in the US, a common name for a shop that sells sandwiches is "delicatessen," which is very often shortened to "deli."

As for what to call someone who works at a deli, I would use "deli worker" or the gender-specific (and very casual) "deli guy" and "deli lady."

Comment: "I think it's somewhat tongue-in-cheek since the sandwiches they sell are of very poor quality." I think they're pretty good myself.

Comment: Sorry @Joel-Anair I used sandwich bar instead of snack bar. I meant the latter in the post as I couldn't look up the former in any dictionary!

Comment: @JoeZ. I agree they're not bad, but works of art they are not. I was overly harsh in my answer and I'll correct it. :)

Comment: As far as mass-produced subs go, yeah they're okay. But I think your current wording is the best: there's nothing incredibly artistic about them. Now, the executive chefs that designed them, when considering how they look, taste, cost, and how easy they are to prepare, that could be considered art. But that would make the teenagers doing the preparing just laborers, not artists.

Comment: I agree that they're unexceptional, but they're still pretty good. Correction accepted. :)

Comment: @corsiKa that's an interesting point about the executive chefs.

Comment: This is an interesting answer but, and you allude to this, Subway corporate jargon is not general English usage.

Answer (score 2):

"Short-order cook" might work if anything else besides sandwiches is prepared there. If not, then "sandwich-maker" as proposed by Mari-Lou A might be best.

Example of use: "The short order cook prepared a sandwich for the irate customer in two minutes flat."

http://www.wisegeek.org/what-is-a-short-order-cook.htm (this description of the job has a sandwich as a example)

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/short-order-cook

Answer (score 2):

As nobody gave the obvious answer yet, I will give it:

There is no word in English for someone who both makes and sells sandwiches.

---

Having said that, *sandwich seller* can be considered in the right context. Because it is high-likely that a sandwich seller is also making the sandwiches. Of course, they might be getting the sandwiches from a wholesale sandwich supplier. Additionally, the term usually refers to a street seller rather than someone who works at a sandwich shop/bar.

Moreover, *sandwich seller* is used as a term who works at a *sandwich shop* in a economy-related book called "Free Market Economics, Second Edition: An Introduction for the General Reader" *By Steven Kates*. I also found this phrase in some other economy related publications.

Comment: Likewise a sandwich-maker *could* also be the owner of a snack bar. The seller is not necessarily the same person who prepares the sandwiches, it's not a given.

Answer (score 0):

Surely we must coin a new term: *Sandwichsta* (*"san(d) WEECH sta"*)

---

But seriously folks: I don't think English has a one-word term for this. "The deli guy/gal" is pretty much as close as I've ever heard.

Answer (score -1):

Would *sandwich monger* be a candidate? Granted this would be a bit more UK-focused, and is generally more focused on the selling and trade than the making.

Comment: That's a good tip

Comment: I think sarniemonger is my new favourite word.